# What is the Hostinger plugin for?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

My hosting is contracted with Hostinger. WordPress recommends that I remove inactive plugins to avoid attacks. One of these plugins is "Hostinger".

Before deleting it I would like to know what this plugin does, to avoid a problem to my Website.

Does anyone know what this plugin does and if I can remove it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Hostinger plugin is used to create an interface between your Wordpress installation and the hosting Control Panel.

It allows you to see Hostinger features, install some recommended plugins and walk you through an onboarding flow.

You can safely uninstall this plugin if you have your WP setup complete.